# Cannot build sysmaster oninit Informix 11.70

Tags: sql, informix

Good afternoon,

I have been all day trying to install Informix Server 11.70 on my computer with Windows 7

I have installed it following the instructions provided with IBM, but when I try to initialize the instance I am getting errors while building sysmaster database. Precisely,

```
511: Cannot modify system catalog (systables)
```

when trying to

```
insert into systables select * from tempsystab;
```

I am executing oninit -iyv as root belonging to Informix-Admin User group...

Any help will be appreciated, I've been all day with this...

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related with Win permission, as we work in a LAN, Informix user was not properly created.